# QTableView sizing issue

Tags: c++

I am using Qt 4.2. I have a window with two separate tables using  the QTableView and QAbstractTableModel. The tables seem to have extra space below the rows ending, and to the right of the columns ending. My solution up to this point with other windows has been to calculate the size of the table (based on cell size, plus a little extra for the border) and set the fixed width and height. This solution is a pain for tables that have different size columns. I am looking for a solution where my QTableView class does not have to set its own fixed size, but rather the table just ends at the last row and column. I do not want to use setStretchLastColumn(). Any suggestions to get these tables to behave properly without having to calculate and set a fixed size would be very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using insertRows()?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that your desired tables would never have any scrollbars, but instead would always grow or shrink as necessary to display the contents of the table exactly?

Comment: James - Yes I have used insertRows(), it does not change the sizing issue.

Comment: Jeremy - They may have scroll bars, because I want to allow the window to be resized smaller (making the table need scroll bars). However, when the window is resized larger (past the need for scroll bars) I want the extra space past the rows/columns to be space for the window. Instead, you can tell that that space is part of the table. I hope that makes sense, let me know if it does not, thank you for your responses.